# Xamarin Forms Shell Tab Bar - Load default view for that Tab

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm looking for a way to reset back to the default page for the tab when a user switches between tabs in a Xamarin Forms Shell based app.

Currently, my app has a number of tabs at the bottom, and a few of them can navigate to other pages (in a wizard type of scenario). Now, currently when a user clicks on a different tab and then returns to that tab - the last page the user navigated to in that tab is displayed - and I need the navigation to be reset to the default page for that tab.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Comment: That is generally the exact opposite of the standard UX for a tabbed interface.  Tabs are supposed to remember their state, so that you can navigate between different parts of an app in parallel.

Comment: @Jason in my case - the first page for a particular tab is a barcode scanning page, with the follow on pages from that page are context specific for that barcode. If user navigates away to a different tab it is safe to assume this particular process has been abandoned and needs to be started from scratch

Comment: You do what you want, I'm just suggesting that's a potentially bad/confusing use of a tabbed interface.  You can always use the `CurrentPageChanged` event to detect a tab switch and reset the page navigation as needed.